# Add one cell upon drag in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation

I am trying to make a `table view` that can add a cell when it's dragged downwards up to a certain `content offset`. Something like the animations in the following links:

[Animation1](https://dribbble.com/shots/4089014-Pull-To-Refresh-iPhone-X)

[Animation2](https://dribbble.com/shots/4137302-Pull-Down-To-Create)

I have tried using the delegate function: `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)` but I'll need to stop the function once the cell is added.
My Code:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y <= -110 {
            cellCount += 1
            dataSource?.append(Model())
            tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .top)
            tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

How to achieve the animations in the links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this Github Repo [FlippingNotch](https://github.com/quickbirdstudios/FlippingNotch)

[quickbirdstudios](https://github.com/quickbirdstudios) has shown how to make first animation